# Is sort value a valid domain property?

Tags: java, android, domain-driven-design

**Background**

I'm building an app that displays a vertical list of items (imagine a file explorer app). An item type can be a folder, in which case a folder can have any number of children items/folders, allowing the user to create/navigate a hierarchy, again like a file system. Instead of the items being ordered alphabetically (etc), the user can manually drag and drop the items to sort them as they please. So, each item has an integer type sort/position property that keeps track of the item's position relative to other items in the current folder. At least, the view models do currently.

**Question**

Does the item's sort/position property belong as a property on the domain objects for the items?

The sort values have no meaning to an individual item on its own. The weird concept here is the recursive/hierarchical nature of items that are folders. Folders type items could be responsible for ensuring that immediate children sort values are valid (sequential/no gaps/no overlaps), and for making changes to the sort order of those children.

But is that correct? Sort order seems like a display related concern. Should there instead be a service that takes sort-less domain entities and applies a sort/position property to those items as they get converted to view models before being displayed?

Answer (score 1):

An Aggregate is a consistency boundary. All business rules should be preserved within that consistency boundary. Putting SortOrder within your Item Aggregate would mean that you cannot ensure that the rules you stated are being upheld, but if you loosen your rules, then you can get away with putting SortOrder here. Specifically, if you remove the constraint that your SortOrder needs to be strictly sequential then you can live with gaps.

If you put SortOrder within a Folder Aggregate then you can maintain the rules you suggested, but there is a cost there as well? What if an Item is deleted or moved to a different Folder? How does the parent Folder get notified? How does it respond? Do you remove the item and re-order?

In this way, the answer depends on which scenarios are more likely and whether the rules are really as you stated them or if you are flexible about them for the purpose of simplifying the implementation.